# How to prevent dependent texture read when sampling from a fullscreen texture

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

Apple recommends avoiding texture reads which use UV coordinates that are calculated in the fragment shader. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html)

Now let's say I am rendering some 3D model, and in the associated fragment shader I need to sample from a full screen texture. The sample position needs to  correspond to the current fragment's position on the screen.

The simplest way that I know of to calculate the UV for sampling this full screen texture would be to use `gl_FragCoord.xy/u_viewportWidth`, but according to Apples guidelines, this would introduce a dependent texture read since there is now a calculation used in order to generate the UV in the pixel shader.

We could pull up the UV calculation to the vertex shader by basically calculating the screen position for each vertex, doing the viewport division to get a UV, and then passing this coordinate as a varying to the fragment shader. However, I question whether or not the UV values would actually be interpolated correctly by the hardware. (Is this even a valid approach?)

Otherwise, is there any way to avoid having to calculate the UV in the pixel shader or is this just impossible?

Comment: "*Apple recommends avoiding texture reads which use UV coordinates that are calculated in the fragment shader.*" No, they don't. They simply say to "be aware" of them and the potential performance implications. Don't misinterpret a simple performance warning as "steer clear at all costs".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I question whether or not the UV values would actually be interpolated correctly by the hardware. (Is this even a valid approach?)

You have good instincts; they won't be interpolated correctly. Perspective correct interpolation will confound this approach, since this is one of those rare cases where you need true linear interpolation. Even OpenGL ES 3.2 doesn't have the `noperspective` qualifier (and yet, Vulkan *requires* support for it. So I'm guessing the ES working group just dropped the ball).

There does not appear to be a way to get a normalized screen coordinate into your fragment shader without computing it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming

Comment: Could you potentially do something where you calculate normalized coordinates *without* perspective division in the vertex shader, and then use `textureProj()` to sample in the fragment shader? I haven't thought it through, just crossed my mind...

Comment: @RetoKoradi: I don't believe that `textureProj` can adjust a non-perspective-correctly interpolated value into a perspective correct interpolated one.